# Unital free semigroup and operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $F_n^+$ be a unital free semigroup generated by $1,...,n$. Let $\alpha= i_1...i_k$ where $i_1,...,i_k\in \{1,...,n\}$ and put $T_{\alpha}:=T_{i_1}...T_{i_k}$ where for any $ i_j\in \{1,...,n\},~ T_i\in B(H)$ . Show that $$||\sum_{|\alpha|=k}T_\alpha T_\alpha^*||\leq ||\sum_{i=1}^n T_iT_i^*||^k$$

for this clearly it's correct for $k=1$. But I could not show this inequality for $k\geq 2$. Please help me.